# Implement Oculus go on unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusgo

just begin to code/work on unity. 
No big trouble to set some camera move or launch animation on standalone plateform.

But when I try Oculus go ... I want to get the same "on click' I've got  on standalone plateform. Ideally I would make a gaze pointer timed, which avoid joystick.

First : Do you know how to display  what you see on the Oculus on unity (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TektJroMwxY at 9:40 for example) ?

And then How could I simply implement a gaze pointer click ? I try the Oculus unity integration (https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/unity-integration/) UI scene but there is too many code to understand quickly everything.

Many thanks for your help, 
Axel

Answer (score 2):

First of all:
**Interesting stuff is not quickly to learn**

Anyway, you need to know that Oculus gaze point do not work as the typical mouse-click. You need to raycast from your camera to stuff (with attached colliders or build some system) to know if you are clicking on it.

Watch deeply on VrInteractiveItem class, as it's how oculus mainly works.